# Open InternetExplorer From C# with new context

Tags: c#

```
var ie = new InternetExplorer { Visible = true };
ie.Navigate("http://google.com");
ie.DocumentComplete += IeDocumentComplete;
```

But when the document is opened, it's like a Ctrl+N in Internet Explorer.
I don't want to keep context and session. I would like a new instance of Internet explorer.

Can you help me please ?

Many Thanks

Comment: Why are you hooking up the DocumentComplete handler after you've requested navigation to occur? For all you know, the document has completed before the call to Navigate returns.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to capture the key board event and pass it to the InternetExpolorer control, if I am not wrong because the key interrupts are sent to your application (and not to your IE Control) it does not work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768335(VS.85).aspx

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example code, I'm guessing your using the InternetExplorer class from ShDocVw.dll?

Instead of using that, try to open Internet Explorer by launching it as a new process...

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe http://www.google.com");
```

That *may* do it, but it may also be down to specific user settings in the browser itself.